# Firestore listener doesn't fire when a reference inside document collection changes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the `addSnapshotListener` to fire when a referenced document inside an other document changes.

I have two tables: `users` and `rooms`.

There is a reference to a user inside `rooms`

`rooms` > `{roomId}` > `room_users` (which is a collection) > `[list of id's]` > reference to a user in each document

[image]

Using the following code I get a reference to this

```
fun getInnerCollection(baseCollection: String, baseDoc: String, collection: String): CollectionReference {
     return FirebaseUtil.firestore
          .collection(baseCollection)
          .document(baseDoc)
          .collection(collection)
     }
```

On this I add an `addSnapshotListener`.

Any time I change (ar add) a field in any of the documents inside `room_users`, the listener fires. However when I changed a property in the `users` table, that is linked in a document (like `OMF1JtKgj3PZaEsUkitj900FIYm1` in the screenshot), the listener doesn't fire.
Because of this I'm not aware when something changes in a referenced document.

How would I make the listener fire when a change occurs inside a referenced object?
Or is adding a listener to every document the only solution?

Comment: I supposed that it cannot be implemented. The Firebase snapshot listener does not can listen to what a reference field points to.

Answer (score 1):

A query can only consider documents in a single collection.  Therefore, a listener on that query can only respond to changes to documents in that single collection.  It will not consider any references to other documents.

If you want to listen to a document that comes from a DocumentReference field, you will need to establish a new listener for each one separately.